# Drupal. how to add a check before saving the form

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

Installed Drupal 7, I work with the module Webform 7.40 ver. 
There is a form in which there are two fields with a choice of dates. 
How to add a check before saving the form, if between the dates of less than 3 days, you do not save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [webform validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation) module